# What are must-have third party XAML Controls

Tags: xaml, controls

As I get myself ready to move my Winform applications to XAML, I was wondering what are the must-have third party XAML controls that will save me developing time and will make my app look shiny with little work?
Thanks,
Nestor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML is markup language rather than a platform.  In fact, you don't even have to use XAML to write WPF applications if you really don't want to.  Since you're talking about converting from WinForms I believe that the question you're asking is more one of which third-party WPF control kits exist, so I'll answer on that assumption.

There are a few companies that have pretty extensive suites.  As Shoban mentioned above, Telerik is one.  You also have Infragistics, Actipro, Component One, to name just a few.

There are also quite a few specialty libraries to aid in Business Intelligence, Graphics Processing and more.

In other words, it's not possibility to make a good recommendation as to specific control libraries, but I can point you in a couple of directions.

[WindowsClient.Net](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/controlgallery/tags/WPF+Controls/default.aspx) attempts to maintain a control gallery (not just for WPF, either).  That's a good place to start.  There are also software sales companies such as ComponentSource which can also set you in a direction or two.

---

*I tried to link the other companies, but SO apparently thinks I'm too much of a noob to be trusted with high-security stuff such as multiple hyperlinks.  :)*

Comment: Yes. I stand corrected: I should have asked about WPF controls, not XAML controls...

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/). They have some nice controls.